# Qt can't get characters from Unicode string

Tags: qt

How can I get Unicode character (QChare type) from Unicode characters string (QString type).?I am trying with operator[] for Qstring object, and with it's member function at(), but it's not helping me(I'm using Qt Creator 2.0.1). I'm begginer in Qt, so this is maybe a simple question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like:

```
QString s("text");
QChar unicodeChar(s.at(0).unicode());
```

Comment: Thank you, for response.I tried it, but it didn't work, it was getting the same result as 
QString s("text");
QChar var = s.at(0);

Comment: I want to remind, that QString s(L"աա"); there is Unicode characters string

Answer (score 0):

If you load your string into a QString, you can still use the .at(index) function.  It will return a QChar which is a single wchar_t (UTF-16).  You can cast that QChar to a wchar_t to get the unicode character.

Comment: Thank you, Keith.I tried, but it wasn't working.I got an empty character, when there was data in my string.Maybe I'm doing somthing wrong...can you please write an example.
I was doing so QString s(L"աա");wchar_t var = (const wchar_t)a.at(0).toLatin1();